# Call C++ executables insider Android

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I am now porting a linux C++ library to Android using JNI. The library porting itself is very straightforward, and I have built a C++ library that can be invoked by Android via JNI. Now my problem is to verify that the library works well in Android environment as well. In the linux development environment, some unit-tests and regression tests are already available. So I was wondering whether I can test the library by taking advantage of all the available unit-test and regression test programs. For example, in linux I have the following binaries:

```
mylib.so 
my_unit_test
my_regression_test
```

Then for Android, I will first `built mylib_android.so`. Then, can I build `my_unit_test_android` and `my_regression_test_android` for Android platform? If it possible, how can I invoke them in the Android simulator and the real device?I have little knowledge about Android, and any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Transform them to libraries with single function and write Android app that will use them.